# Does waitForElementVisible not search for input elements?

Tags: e2e-testing, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am using nightwatch.js to perform end-to-end testing and have to use a roundabout method for a `waitForElementVisible` [command](https://v12.nightwatchjs.org/api/waitForElementVisible.html) to work as expected. For example, my code below:

```
browser.waitForElementVisible(".profile label[for='Admin']") // works
browser.waitForElementVisible(".profile label[for='Admin'] input[id='Admin']") // breaks
```

For further clarification, I am testing to see if a radio button is visible. The radio button's DOM elements is as such:

```html
<div class='profile'>
  <div class='roleSelector'>
    <label for="Admin">
      <input type="radio" id="Admin" class="Admin">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such specific case.

Did you try using '.profile input[id='Admin']' ?

Hope that serves your purpose at hand.